# LWC lightning datatable row size

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, css, lightning-datatable

I need to resize the rows in lightning datatable LWC
All I can found was column resizing in documentation of lightning data table of LWC

Please suggest me any solution regarding resizing the rows.

Comment: if you want to set a custom width use `initialWidth`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, That was for Columns width...

I used padding in CSS..it worked